# If $X$ is bounded then $\inf\{\mathbb E\:Z : Z\text{ simple}, Z \geq X\: a.s\}=\sup\{\mathbb E\:Y : Y\text{ simple}, Y \leq X\: a.s\}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> If $X$ is bounded  then
> $$\inf\{\mathbb E\:Z : Z\text{ simple}, Z \geq X\: a.s\}=\sup\{\mathbb E\:Y : Y\text{ simple}, Y \leq X\: a.s\}$$

The definition of a random variable $X$ is bounded,

A random variable $X$ is bounded if there exists $M < \infty$ such that $|X|\leq M \: a.s.\:($Almost Sure$)$

Define $L=\sup\{\mathbb E\:Y : Y\text{ simple}, Y \leq X\: a.s\}$ and $U=\inf\{\mathbb E\:Z : Z\text{ simple}, Z \geq X\: a.s\}$. I need to show $U=L$. But I couldn't come up with any idea how can I do that.

It would be great help if anyone help me  to figure out this.

Comment: Note that this just means that a bounded function (in a finite measure space) is (Lebesgue) integrable.

Answer (score 2):

Choose $M>0$ such that $|X|\leq M$. By bisecting the range of $X$,
we can always construct sequence of simple random variables $(Y_{n})$
such that $|Y_{n}|\leq M$, $Y_{1}\leq Y_{2}\leq\ldots\leq X$ and
$Y_{n}\rightarrow X$ pointwisely.

Explicitly, define $f_{n}:[-M,M]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=-2^{n}+1}^{2^{n}}(\frac{k-1}{2^{n}})M\cdot1_{[M\cdot\frac{k-1}{2^{n}},M\cdot\frac{k}{2^{n}})}(x).
$$
One can verify that $f_{1}(x)\leq f_{2}(x)\leq\ldots\leq x$ and $f_{n}(x)\rightarrow x$ for each $x\in[-M,M]$. Define $Y_{n}=f_{n}\circ X$,
then $(Y_{n})$ has the desired property.

For each $n$, we have $E[Y_{n}]\in\{E[Y]\mid Y\leq X\mbox{ a.e. and }Y\mbox{ is simple}\}$.
Therefore, $E[Y_{n}]\leq\sup\{E[Y]\mid Y\leq X\mbox{ a.e. and }Y\mbox{ is simple}\}\leq E[X]$.
On the other hand, by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, $E[Y_{n}]\rightarrow E[X]$.
It follows that $\sup\{E[Y]\mid Y\leq X\mbox{ a.e. and }Y\mbox{ is simple}\}=E[X]$.

To prove that $\inf\{E[Y]\mid Y\geq X\mbox{ a.e. and }Y\mbox{ is simple}\}=E[X]$,
one replaces $f_{n}$ by $g_{n}$, where $g_{n}:[-M,M]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
is defined by
$$
g_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=-2^{n}+1}^{2^{n}}(\frac{k}{2^{n}})M\cdot1_{[M\cdot\frac{k-1}{2^{n}},M\cdot\frac{k}{2^{n}})}(x).
$$
Note that $g_{1}(x)\geq g_{2}(x)\geq\ldots\geq x$ and $g_{n}(x)\rightarrow x$
for each $x\in[-M,M]$.

Comment: Thanks(+1), @Danny Pak-Keung Chan. Could you tell me how you guess the $f_n$? I was really wondering how to come up with that when I am at exam. It will be great help if you can describe it.

Comment: The construction of $f_n$ is well-known in Lebesgue integration theory. Recall the proof of the important result: If $f\geq 0$ is measurable, there exists a sequence $(f_n)$ of simple measurable functions such that $0\leq f_1 \leq f_2 \leq f$ and $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwisely.

Comment: But how could you get (construction) the expression (like any insight), $$
f_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=-2^{n}+1}^{2^{n}}(\frac{k-1}{2^{n}})M\cdot1_{[M\cdot\frac{k-1}{2^{n}},M\cdot\frac{k}{2^{n}})}(x).
$$ Because I think I wasn't getting any intuition by how to get that.